# In my map editor, how can I make the tiles "stick" at 32 pixels multiples?

Tags: c#, xna, maps

I have a problem with making map editor in XNA.
I'm making a 2D tile based map editor.

The problem is, I need every tile I put in map editor to be X: 0, or X: 32, or X:64 and so on, not 1.10, 2.99, 5.62, etc. You see, it has to be exactly i*32 tiles, where i is whatever number, not decimal. Thank you if you help.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D) is a great OpenSource XNA map editor. You can fully customize the ground grid and enable grid snapping to make maps. Also since it's opensource you can edit it to suit your exact needs.

Comment: That's called an integer... Can you please better describe your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to "snap" coordinates to a grid is this:

```
    int objX = (int) Math.Floor(mouseX/tileWidth)*tileWidth;
    int objY = (int) Math.Floor(mouseY/tileHeight)*tileHeight;
```

Comment: If the tiles are powers of two, e.g. 32, then you can simply AND off the lower bits, objX = mouseX & (32-1);

Comment: @PatrickB Nice tip, I prefer `objX = mouseX & 0x1f`

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/14702/12111), but I'm currently using

```
                            // for example 100 - (100 % 32 (which is 4)) = 94 
Vector2 placementPosition = mousePosition 
               - new Vector2(mousePosition.X % 32, mousePosition.Y % 32);
```

which works perfectly, too